# Rails App: Issue with custom path helper for a nested path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested

I have a nested route that looks like this...

`get  'participants/:participant_id/surveys/:survey_id', to: 'surveys#take_survey',  as: :take_survey`

My question is this. I know that i get a path helper like this, 'surveys_path(@survey)' for a route like...

`get 'surveys/:id', to: 'surveys#show'`

So since in the first route I listed above ive set a custom path name that gives me the helper, 'take_survey_path'...

how to I use the helper 'take_survey_path()' to retrieve a survey?

basically... 'take_survey_path(what_do_I_put_here_to_retrieve_a_survey?)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was very simple.

'take_survey_path', as I had it set up for my nested path, takes two arguments...

`'take_survey_path(participant_id, survey_id)'`